# How to avoid multiple categories to one sql record

Tags: sql

Can someone help me with my query below?

- I am getting the same `member_id` with two     different values in the `event_status_reason_desc` column.
- I am getting 'Entered in Error' on one row in the column, which is what I want, however
- I am also getting `NULL` in the same column, but I do not want that one.

Can someone help me?

```
SELECT * 
FROM openquery(ccms_rpt, '
    select 
        a.member_id, b.member_first_name, b.member_last_name, a.event_type,
        d.event_type_desc, a.event_date, a.authorization_number, g.refer_to_provider, 
        c.ccms_user_last_name, c.ccms_user_first_name,
        case
            when a.event_type = fe.event_type then (fe.event_status_reason_desc)
            when a.event_type = ''04'' then(ge.event_status_reason_desc)
        end as Event_Status_Reason_Desc

    from ccmsdba_txc_prd.event a
    join ccmsdba_txc_prd.member b 
        on a.member_id = b.member_id
    join ccmsdba_txc_prd.ccms_all_users c 
        on a.ccms_id = c.ccms_id
    join ccmsdba_txc_prd.zl_event_type d 
        on a.event_type = d.event_type
    left join ccmsdba_txc_prd.event_admission f 
        on a.authorization_number = f.authorization_number
    left join ccmsdba_txc_prd.event_referral g 
        on a.authorization_number =             g.authorization_number
    left join ccmsdba_txc_prd.zl_event_status_reason fe 
        on f.event_status_reason = fe.event_status_reason
    left join ccmsdba_txc_prd.zl_event_status_reason ge 
        on g.event_status_reason = ge.event_status_reason

    where a.event_status = ''IP''
    and a.authorization_number = ''A170''
')
```

Comment: Example output with unwanted record displayed may help

Comment: It will not let me post a picture.

Comment: If you can re-create the issue on sqlfiddle.com I'm sure we could figure it out as well.  I think it's one of the following: 1) data stemming from an improper join (missing criteria on the join) 2) duplicate data existing that you're not expecting in a table causing a second record to appear; an unhanded case type. the a.event_Type is not 04, nor is it equal to fe.event_Type.  You may want to add an `else` then 'X' to see if it's the problem.

Comment: Was it a combination of problems or was there one specifically in the above 3 that isolated the data problem?

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have ONLY two problems:
1. you have duplicate records for "**authorization_number**" within 
"**event_admission**" or "**event_referral**" tables. Or you have duplicates for "**event_status_reason**" within "**zl_event_status_reason**"
You have to clean the data or use sub-query to get distinct values.

2. You are getting 'Entered in Error' on one row in the column...
   You did not specified the column, but assume you do not have nulls in that column.
   Most probably, you just do not have corresponding records in one of the LEFT joined tables.
   If you really need LEFT join and do not need NULLs you can Use ISNULL function. Something like this:

   ISNULL([My column],'Not Null Value')